# elapsed time in seconds using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I usually seed my RNG by the following time, obtained by a call to `time.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there an equivalent to `static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))` in the Boost-library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the time using `boost::posix_time`. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734375/c-boost-get-current-time-in-milliseconds). Ex:

```
boost::posix_time::time_duration diff = tick - now;
diff.total_milliseconds();
```

You can also use the [C++11 chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), if you can use C++11. Ex:

```
int elapsed_milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count();
```

With these two methods, you can get the number of milliseconds from the start of the day, and then assign it to your seed.

Comment: For my pc, it turned out that **boost** is quite faster (roughly a 4.20 factor) than **chrono**