# Posix_Time Time Duration Doesn't have all the functions

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, time

I am trying to use posix_time::time_duration to find the total number of milliseconds of the time. I looked at code online, and found this: [How to print current time (with milliseconds) using C++ / C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077299/how-to-print-current-time-with-milliseconds-using-c-c11).

However, for some reason my posix_time::time_duration doesn't have access to the total_milliseconds function, or several of the functions (like is_negative, invert_sign, etc). I am wondering why this is the case and how I can fix it. I included the header file, #include , in my code. I have the boost libraries installed on my computer.

Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I don't even have the hours(), minutes(), or seconds functions available to me too.

Comment: Show some code how you're trying to use it. I'd guess you're struggling on compiler or linker errors (which ones exactly?). Probably you've just forgotten to specify the correct libraries you'll need to link with your program. Milliseconds resolution should be available with any posix environment.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from that link and the functions were not there. Are there any specific libraries I need to link?

Comment: I already have boost_system

Comment: `boost_system` seems to be appropriate. Could you please edit your question as I've been asking for. Show some code, show the concrete compiler/linker errors you get. Did you setup the paths to the boost libraries to use correctly (`-L` option for the linking stage). Also on some environments you'll need to setup names for very specific build variants (e.g. on Windows using MinGw/Debug/Multithreaded it's boost_system-mgw46-mt-d-1_51).