# Timestamp in milliseconds gives me 10 digit in C++?

Tags: c++, date, boost, time, milliseconds

I am trying to retrieve Current Time in milliseconds using boost library.. Below is my code which I am using to get the current time in milliseconds.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
boost::posix_time::time_duration duration( time.time_of_day() );
std::cout << duration.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;

uint64_t timestampInMilliseconds = duration.total_milliseconds() // will this work or not?

std::cout << timestampInMilliseconds << std::endl;
```

But this prints out in 10 digit which is like `17227676`.. I am running my code on my ubuntu machine.. And I believe it is always 13 digit long value? Isn't so?

After computing the timestamp in milliseconds, I need to use below formula on that -

```
int end = (timestampInMilliseconds / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24))  % 14
```

But somehow I am not sure whether timestampInMilliseconds which I am getting is right or not?

First of all should I be using boost::posix or not? I am assuming there might be some better way.. I am running code on my ubuntu machine..

**Update:-**

As this piece of bash script prints out timestampInMilliseconds which is of 13 digit..

```
date +%s%N | cut -b1-13
```

Comment: If you have the value `1234`, would you expect it to be printed as e.g. `0000001234`? Leading zeroes are never printed unless requested to.

Comment: I see.. So this timestamp in milliseconds what I am getting in my code will be number of milliseconds since epoch?

Comment: That value `17227676` is a *duration*, not a timestamp. It's only around 4 hours and 47 minutes.

Comment: hmmm.. Then I am doing something wrong in my C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you use `time_of_day()` which returns (from [this reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.ptime_class))

> Get the time offset in the day.

So from the value you provided in the question I can deduce that you ran this program at 4:47 am.

Instead you might want to use e.g. the `to_tm()` to get a [`struct tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) and construct your time in milliseconds from there.

Also note that the `%s` format to the `date` command (and the `strftime` function) is the number of *seconds* since the epoch, not the number of milliseconds.

---

If you look at the `tm` structure, you will see that it has the number of years (since 1900, so subtract 70 here), days into the year, and then hours,, minutes and seconds into the day. All these can be used to calculate the time *in seconds* easily.

And that *in seconds* is the problem here. If you look at e.g. the POSIX [`time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) function you see that

> shall return the value of time in seconds since the Epoch

If you want an accurate millisecond resolution you simply can't use the `ptime` (where the `p` stands for POSIX). If you want millisecond resolution you either have to use e.g. system functions that returns the time in higher resolutions (like [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html)), or you can see e.g. [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6734625/440558).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. Can you provide me an example on how to construct my time in milliseconds epoch using struct tm.. I recently started with C++ so finding it little bit difficult.. Thanks..

Comment: @SSH Updated my answer, with (among other things) a link to an answer that seems to be exactly what you want.