# How to use boost to track real time instead of user+sys?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, timer

I'm using `boost::timer` to time a section of my code. If I run the code with one thread:

```
$ time ./runfoo 1
Took 2.08s

real    0m2.086s
user    0m1.611s
sys     0m0.475s
```

`2.08` is the output of `t.elapsed()`.

Yet if I run the code with 4 threads:

```
$ time ./runfoo 4
Took 2.47s

real    0m1.022s
user    0m1.834s
sys     0m0.628s
```

It seems to be tracking user+sys time, not real time.

How do I make it track real time? I'm using Boost 1.46. To be more specific, the timer is in the main thread, which just calls a function that ends up using the multiple threads.

EDIT: The relevant source looks something like this:

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
boost::thread_group pool; 
boost::asio::io_service::work work(ios);
pool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
pool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
pool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
pool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
{
    boost::timer t;

    function_which_posts_to_ios(ios);

    printf("Took %.2fs\n", t.elapsed();
}
```

As to what output I expect, I'd like the program in the 2nd run to print `"Took 1.02s"` instead of `"Took 2.47s"`, as `1.02s` was the actual amount of seconds that elapsed.

Comment: "Real" time, like the one returned by [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html)?

Comment: Yes, the one labelled "real" as time's output.

Comment: Could you show the source to `runfoo`? Without it, we can't begin to assess what output you might expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are using the [deprecated Version 1 timers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/timer/doc/original_timer.html) where the semantics of `elapsed()` was not consistent across platforms, wall-clock time on some and CPU time on others. In the [Version 2 `cpu_timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html), the `elapsed()` method returns a struct which has distinct members for real, user, and system time.

If you cannot use the Version 2 API, you can use `boost::posix_time` instead to measure wall clock time. See [c++ boost get current time in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734375/c-boost-get-current-time-in-milliseconds).

Comment: Yea those don't exist for the version of boost I'm using. Looks like the question you linked has something I could use - thanks!